# 301 redirect conflicts with cname redirect for both naked and www URL

Tags: domains, htaccess, 301-redirect, cname, dns-servers

Client had created a cname redirect for their www url which goes to their new web address, they were told to create a 301 redirect for the naked url but it's conflicting with the cname and the www url no longer redirects. How do I fix this?

Comment: This question is somewhat similar to this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53396/seo-impact-of-using-cname-host-both-naked-and-www-url especially the confusion about redirects and CNAME records.   Are these questions somehow related?

Answer (score 3):

A CNAME is **NOT** a redirect.  A CNAME is a type of DNS record that tells the DNS resolver to do another DNS lookup under a different name.

A DNS record for a site often looks like:

```
example.com. IN A 69.9.64.11
www.example.com IN CNAME example.com.
```

That means that when a user types in `example.com`, then:

1. The DNS client queries `example.com` and gets `69.9.64.11`
2. The web browser issues a request to `69.9.64.11` and sends the hostname `example.com`
3. The web server returns the index document
4. The user sees the content and `example.com` in their URL bar

When the user types in `www.example.com` then

1. The DNS client queries `www.example.com` and is told to look at `example.com`
2. The DNS client queries `example.com` and gets `69.9.64.11`
3. The web browser issues a request to `69.9.64.11` and sends the hostname `www.example.com`
4. The web server returns the index document
5. The user sees the content and `www.example.com` in their URL bar

If you want to redirect one to the other, you don't need to change DNS at all.  301 redirects can be implemented regardless of DNS configuration.  Both `A` records and `CNAME` records work fine.  If you want to use 301 redirects from `www.example.com` to `example.com` then the steps that are taken when a user types in `www.example.com` would be:

1. The DNS client queries `www.example.com` and is told to look at `example.com`
2. The DNS client queries `example.com` and gets `69.9.64.11`
3. The web browser issues a request to `69.9.64.11` and sends the hostname `www.example.com`
4. The web server returns a 301 redirect to `http://example.com/`
5. The DNS client queries `example.com` and gets `69.9.64.11`
6. The web browser issues a request to `69.9.64.11` and sends the hostname `example.com`
7. The web server returns the index document
8. The user sees the content and `example.com` in their URL bar

To make this work, your web server needs to be configured to issue the 301 redirect response unless the domain name is canonical.