# Why is CNAME pointing to IP instead of URL?

Tags: dns, cname

My CNAME setting is [image]

I expect ms.fbny.org to be an alias of music-school.fbny.org. However when I go to ms.fbny.org, it actually goes to music-school.fbny.org's IP instead of music-school.fbny.org itself. So it is opening another website hosted on the same IP. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: CNAMEs have never pointed to URLs. See [A CNAME is NOT a redirect](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53504/14543)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the default behavior. The web server should be configured to serve from the correct document root when the request comes from a specific subdomain.

For example, if you use apache, you should configure virtual hosts appropriately.

Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Above page contains the below example:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Request from `www.example.org` will be served from the folder `/www/example2` and those from `www.example.com` will be served from `/www/example1`. Moreover, apache considers the first entry to be the default when there is no match for a server name.

(In case you use apache) your new subdomain (for which you had created a CNAME) may not be having a matching entry and hence default document root of the main domain is being used.